# rosmake of sick_tim3xx package failed : says permission denied on SickTim3xx.cfg

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using ros-groovy on ubuntu 12.04

after running

```
$ rosmake sick_tim3xx
```

i get the output

```
[ rosmake ] rosmake starting...                                                 
[ rosmake ] Packages requested are: ['sick_tim3xx']                             
[ rosmake ] Logging to directory /home/piyush/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20140504-222452
[ rosmake ] Expanded args ['sick_tim3xx'] to:
['sick_tim3xx']                   
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> catkin [ make ]                                        
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< catkin ROS_NOBUILD in package catkin
 No Makefile in package catkin
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> genmsg [ make ]                                        
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> cpp_common [ make ]                                    
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< genmsg ROS_NOBUILD in package genmsg
 No Makefile in package genmsg
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> rospack [ make ]                                       
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> genlisp [ make ]                                       
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> genpy [ make ]                                         
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< cpp_common ROS_NOBUILD in package cpp_common
 No Makefile in package cpp_common
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> gencpp [ make ]                                        
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< genlisp ROS_NOBUILD in package genlisp
 No Makefile in package genlisp
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< rospack ROS_NOBUILD in package rospack
 No Makefile in package rospack
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rostime [ make ]                                       
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> roslib [ make ]                                        
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< genpy ROS_NOBUILD in package genpy
 No Makefile in package genpy
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> roslang [ make ]                                       
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rostime ROS_NOBUILD in package rostime
 No Makefile in package rostime
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> roscpp_traits [ make ]                                 
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< gencpp ROS_NOBUILD in package gencpp
 No Makefile in package gencpp
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< roslib ROS_NOBUILD in package roslib
 No Makefile in package roslib
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> rosunit [ make ]                                       
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> message_generation [ make ]                            
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< roslang ROS_NOBUILD in package roslang
 No Makefile in package roslang
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< roscpp_traits ROS_NOBUILD in package roscpp_traits
 No Makefile in package roscpp_traits
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> roscpp_serialization [ make ]                          
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> xmlrpcpp [ make ]                                      
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< rosunit ROS_NOBUILD in package rosunit
 No Makefile in package rosunit
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> rosconsole [ make ]                                    
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< message_generation ROS_NOBUILD in package message_generation
 No Makefile in package message_generation
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> rosgraph [ make ]                                      
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< roscpp_serialization ROS_NOBUILD in package roscpp_serialization
 No Makefile in package roscpp_serialization
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> message_runtime [ make ]                               
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< xmlrpcpp ROS_NOBUILD in package xmlrpcpp
 No Makefile in package xmlrpcpp
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> rosclean [ make ]                                      
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< rosconsole ROS_NOBUILD in package rosconsole
 No Makefile in package rosconsole
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< message_runtime ROS_NOBUILD in package message_runtime
 No Makefile in package message_runtime
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< rosclean ROS_NOBUILD in package rosclean
 No Makefile in package rosclean
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> std_msgs [ make ]                                      
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< rosgraph ROS_NOBUILD in package rosgraph
 No Makefile in package rosgraph
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> rosparam [ make ]                                      
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> rosmaster [ make ]                                     
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< std_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package std_msgs
 No Makefile in package std_msgs
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosgraph_msgs [ make ]                                 
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< rosparam ROS_NOBUILD in package rosparam
 No Makefile in package rosparam
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> geometry_msgs [ make ]                                 
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> diagnostic_msgs [ make ]                               
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosgraph_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package rosgraph_msgs
 No Makefile in package rosgraph_msgs
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> roscpp [ make ]                                        
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< rosmaster ROS_NOBUILD in package rosmaster
 No Makefile in package rosmaster
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< diagnostic_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package diagnostic_msgs
 No Makefile in package diagnostic_msgs
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> rospy [ make ]                                         
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< roscpp ROS_NOBUILD in package roscpp
 No Makefile in package roscpp
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosout [ make ]                                        
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< geometry_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package geometry_msgs
 No Makefile in package geometry_msgs
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> sensor_msgs [ make ]                                   
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< rospy ROS_NOBUILD in package rospy
 No Makefile in package rospy
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosout ROS_NOBUILD in package rosout
 No Makefile in package rosout
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> roslaunch [ make ]                                     
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< sensor_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package sensor_msgs
 No Makefile in package sensor_msgs
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< roslaunch ROS_NOBUILD in package roslaunch
 No Makefile in package roslaunch
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rostest [ make ]                                       
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rostest ROS_NOBUILD in package rostest 30/40 Complete ]
 No Makefile in package rostest
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> topic_tools [ make ]                                   
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> diagnostic_updater [ make ]                            
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< topic_tools ROS_NOBUILD in package topic_tools
 No Makefile in package topic_tools
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosbag [ make ]                                        
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< diagnostic_updater ROS_NOBUILD in package diagnostic_updater
 No Makefile in package diagnostic_updater
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> self_test [ make ]                                     
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosbag ROS_NOBUILD in package rosbag
 No Makefile in package rosbag
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosmsg [ make ]                                        
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< self_test ROS_NOBUILD in package self_test
 No Makefile in package self_test
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosmsg ROS_NOBUILD in package rosmsg
 No Makefile in package rosmsg
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosservice [ make ]                                    
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosservice ROS_NOBUILD in package rosservice
 No Makefile in package rosservice
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> dynamic_reconfigure [ make ]                           
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< dynamic_reconfigure ROS_NOBUILD in package dynamic_reconfigure
 No Makefile in package dynamic_reconfigure
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> driver_base [ make ]                                   
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< driver_base ROS_NOBUILD in package driver_base
 No Makefile in package driver_base
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> sick_tim3xx [ make ]                                   
[ rosmake ] Last 40 linesck_tim3xx: 3.4 sec ]        [ 1 Active 39/40 Complete ]
{-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  -- This workspace overlays: /opt/ros/groovy
  -- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/python
  -- Python version: 2.7
  -- Using Debian Python package layout
  -- Using CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING: ON
  -- Skip enable_testing() for dry packages
  -- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /home/piyush/ros_packages/sick_tim3xx/build/test_results
  -- Found gtest sources under '/usr/src/gtest': gtests will be built
  -- catkin 0.5.86
  -- Using these message generators: gencpp;genlisp;genpy
  [rosbuild] Including /opt/ros/groovy/share/roslisp/rosbuild/roslisp.cmake
  [rosbuild] Including /opt/ros/groovy/share/roscpp/rosbuild/roscpp.cmake
  [rosbuild] Including /opt/ros/groovy/share/rospy/rosbuild/rospy.cmake
  MSG: gencfg_cpp on:SickTim3xx.cfg
  [gendeps] Finding dependencies for /home/piyush/ros_packages/sick_tim3xx/cfg/SickTim3xx.cfg
  
  -- Configuring done
  -- Generating done
  CMake Warning:
    Manually-specified variables were not used by the project:
  
      CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE
  
  
  -- Build files have been written to: /home/piyush/ros_packages/sick_tim3xx/build
  cd build && make -j4 -l4
  make[1]: Entering directory `/home/piyush/ros_packages/sick_tim3xx/build'
  make[2]: Entering directory `/home/piyush/ros_packages/sick_tim3xx/build'
  make[3]: Entering directory `/home/piyush/ros_packages/sick_tim3xx/build'
  make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/piyush/ros_packages/sick_tim3xx/build'
  make[3]: Entering directory `/home/piyush/ros_packages/sick_tim3xx/build'
  [ 50%] Generating ../cfg/cpp/sick_tim3xx/SickTim3xxConfig.h, ../docs/SickTim3xxConfig.dox, ../docs/SickTim3xxConfig-usage.dox, ../src/sick_tim3xx/cfg/SickTim3xxConfig.py, ../docs/SickTim3xxConfig.wikidoc
 
 **make[3]: execvp: ../cfg/SickTim3xx.cfg: Permission denied
  make[3]: *** [../cfg/cpp/sick_tim3xx/SickTim3xxConfig.h] Error 127
  make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/piyush/ros_packages/sick_tim3xx/build'
  make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/ROSBUILD_gencfg_cpp.dir/all] Error 2
  make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/piyush/ros_packages/sick_tim3xx/build'
  make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
  make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/piyush/ros_packages/sick_tim3xx/build'**

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
[ rosmake ] Output from build of package sick_tim3xx written to:
[ rosmake ]    /home/piyush/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20140504-222452/sick_tim3xx/build_output.log
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< sick_tim3xx [FAIL] [ 3.39 seconds ]                    
[ rosmake ] Halting due to failure in package sick_tim3xx. 
[ rosmake ] Waiting for other threads to complete.
[ rosmake ] Results:                                                            
[ rosmake ] Built 40 packages with 1 failures.                                  
[ rosmake ] Summary output to directory                                         
[ rosmake ] /home/piyush/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20140504-222452
```

I HAVE HIGHLIGHTED THE PART THAT SEEMS TO BE THE PROBLEM

permissions of the

```
piyush@TheCoolStuffStation:~/ros_packages/sick_tim3xx/cfg$ roscd sick_tim3xx/
piyush@TheCoolStuffStation:~/ros_packages/sick_tim3xx$ ls -lah cfg
total 24K
drwxrwxr-x  3 piyush piyush 4.0K May  5 19:59 .
drwxrwxr-x 12 piyush piyush 4.0K May  5 20:00 ..
drwxrwxr-x  3 piyush piyush 4.0K May  5 19:59 cpp
-rw-rw-r--  1 piyush piyush 3.2K Dec 14 02:30 SickTim3xx.cfg
-rw-rw-r--  1 piyush piyush 3.7K Dec 14 02:30 SickTim3xx.cfg~
-rw-rw-r--  1 piyush piyush 1.3K Dec 14 02:46 SickTim3xx.cfgc
piyush@TheCoolStuffStation:~/ros_packages/sick_tim3xx$ git status
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
piyush@TheCoolStuffStation:~/ros_packages/sick_tim3xx$ cd ..
piyush@TheCoolStuffStation:~/ros_packages$ whoami
piyush
piyush@TheCoolStuffStation:~/ros_packages$
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/160471/rosmake-of-sick_tim3xx-package-failed-:-says-permission-denied-on-sicktim3xx.cfg/) by [hgtc-dp](https://answers.ros.org/users/15556/hgtc-dp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2014-05-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You've probably run `make` using `sudo` before (you shouldn't do that), so you'll have to check the permissions on those folders. The easiest way to fix it would be to remove the build folder (using `sudo`) and try again.

**Edit 1:** Can you edit your question and paste the output of the following commands there?

```
roscd sick_tim3xx
ls -lah cfg
git status
whoami
```

**Edit 2:** Thanks for adding that info. Something weird is going on: you seem to have deleted the `sick_tim3xx/.git` directory, for example. Please delete the whole `sick_tim3xx` directory and run:

```
git clone -b groovy https://github.com/uos/sick_tim3xx.git
```

Then start over.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2014-05-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hgtc-dp](https://answers.ros.org/users/15556/hgtc-dp/) on 2014-05-05**:
I tried it but i am getting the same error. I know for sure that rosmake is working fine as I have built other packages. Permissions attached with cfg folder are drwxrwxr-x(same for all folders in that directory). And with SickTim3xx.cfg -rw-rw-r-- do i need to change something in these. Thanks alot

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2014-05-05**:
It's not just the permissions, but also which user the files belong to. I've edited my answer.

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2014-05-05**:
Also, maybe the file isn't there at all. Try a `git reset --hard`.

**Comment by [hgtc-dp](https://answers.ros.org/users/15556/hgtc-dp/) on 2014-05-06**:
Thanks a lot it worked. Earlier I was downloading the .zip file and then extracting the package. Could you tell me why it could have been failing

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2014-05-06**:
No idea. Somehow you didn't get all necessary files in the right places. Glad it works now for you. :-)